# Do I need a comma before and after "of course" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

Do I need a comma before and after "of course" in the following sentence?

... that includes of course my mom and Lidia.

Comment: Typically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need two commas as you suggest before and after.  The test for this is the sentence should read as without the two commas and words between them.  Remove the phrase "of course" and the sentence would still make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you  need to have comma.
            That includes of course,my mom and lidia.

Comment: Two commas are needed.